# How to send a file from html to node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a server in node using express, and a simple home page in html that use recorder.js to create an audio file.

Now what I want to do is to send the audio file to my server.js so I can use it there (without downloading it).

In the html :

```
recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
  url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  au = document.createElement('audio');
  hf = document.createElement('a');

  au.controls = true;
  au.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
  li.appendChild(au);
  li.appendChild(hf);
  recordingslist.appendChild(li);
});
```

The audio file is stocked on an url that the client creates.

How could I send this audio file to my server.js? I haven't seen any similar question on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) Web API. You could use the postBlobToServer() function defined below as the callback for recorder.exportWAV() instead of your anonymous function. There is a second function included to generate a random file name for the sound file.

On the server side you will need to capture the "wav_blob" field and save the file.

```
function generateFilename() {
  // Generates a random 6 character string suitable for a filename
  var filename = "";
  var dictionary = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  for (var i=0;i < 6; i++)
    filename += dictionary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length));
  return filename;
}

function postBlobToServer(blob) {
  // Form field for blob file
  var blob_field = "wav_blob";
  // Generate a random file name
  var wav_filename = generateFilename() + ".wav";
  // The URL for the form POST action
  var server_url = "http://server.com/path";
  // Create a new FormData object
  // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
  var formData = new FormData();
  // Add the blob_field to the form
  formData.append(blob_field, blob, wav_filename);
  // Set up the AJAX request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Open the connection
  xhr.open("POST", server_url, true);
  // Set up a handler for when the request finishes
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // File uploaded successfully
      // might want to notify the user
    } else {
      alert("An error occurred!");
    }
  };
  // Send the data
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FormData and filename isn't so important if you just send the binaries. Then it also becomes easier to save it on the fs since you won't need any body parser

Client:

```
recorder && recorder.exportWAV(blob => 
  fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: blob})
)
```

Server:

```
var fs = require('fs')

var dest = fs.createWriteStream('myOutput.wav')
req.pipe(dest)
```